# Token authentication - where to store the token

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, access-token

I am working with PHP and Laravel at the moment, I have a restful api that the user needs to authenticate with to make sure they can only access things they own etc.

What I want to know is where should the token from the server be saved on the client? In a session a cookie? The servers database?

Comment: Well a session uses a cookie to identify, and saves the data either on the server hd, or in a database.

Comment: So save it in a cookie, and make the cookie valid for as long as the token?

Comment: If your building an API then cookies won't help you! You should generate a token, store it in the DB or cache and then have them send the token on every request.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to go the following route:

1. the user logs into your site and requests a API usage token
2. when a new request to your API comes in, compare the token from the incomming request, with the token in the db. if it is found, it's a valid request. the REST client could use the `Authorization` header to send the token.
3. send the answer for the request

While the login system of your website, might be session-based with cookies on client-side, the REST API is token-based and doesn't need a cookie or session.

Please take a look at this for more details:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/141434/111803